# Nice CSS badge - can you give me a hand?

Tags: css, badge

I want to implement badges like on Stack Overflow. Maybe you can give me some nice CSS code?

Comment: Please clarify what is SO? Thanks in advance

Comment: Nice CSS badges? You don't need no stinking Nice CSS badges.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Introducing the brand new

### [Stack Overflow BadgeMaker 3000](http://jsfiddle.net/KjAWh/32/)

#### It makes Badges™

Just pop in a name, tell it what color you want your shiny new badge to be, and you're all set!

<sup>Browser support: All modern browsers, up to and including IE7. Round corners not supported in IE8 and below.</sup>

Comment: nm, it did on a postback, go figure

Comment: Finding this was the best part of my day!

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you can use the nice [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and take a peek at how SO does it.

Comment: not sure whether to -1 you for unnecessary sarcasm or +1 you for making me giggle. :p will just leave it at 0 i think. :)

Comment: It is nice that people are so nice to each other.

Comment: @Thomas Clayson: I fail to see sarcasm in this answer... That's one of the ways I would have done it.

Comment: @animuson:  It's nice to hear from you.  Sarcasm is not nice at all, but this entire thread is rather nice, don't you think?

Comment: I just got a "Nice Answer" badge for this answer! Yay!

Comment: Matti just won himself a ... um ... Nice Answer badge!! How appropriate. :)  (OK, back to work now)

Comment: Thank you man, I didn't want to copy all the css of badge, I wanted something different. Congrats with your "Nice answer" badge, hope you will enjoy that.

Answer (score 1):

You mean rounded corners? It uses CSS3 rounded corners:

```
border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
```

Comment: I can't wait until someone points out that using Firebug wouldn't actually yield all of these, because anything Firefox doesn't support gets ignored in its views. Well, it does have a raw request viewer, though...

Answer (score 1):

Or you can run a search for 'badge' on their CSS file:

```
.badge,.badge-tag{color:#fff!important;background-color:#333;border:1px solid #333;margin:0 3px 3px 0;padding:0 6px 0 3px;display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;line-height:1.9;-moz-border-radius:6px;-webkit-border-radius:6px;}
.badge:hover,.badge-tag:hover{border:1px solid #555;background-color:#555;text-decoration:none;}
.badge-tag:hover{color:#fff!important;border:2px solid #555;}
.badge-tag{color:#333!important;border:2px solid #333;background-color:#eee;}
```